# Read fixed-width format, where the widths are inferred from the column headers

Tags: r, dataframe, read.table

I have a rather odd file format that I need to read.  It has space-separated columns, but the column widths must be inferred from the header.

In addition, there are some bogus lines that must be ignored, both blank and non-blank.

A representation of the data:

```
The first line contains some text that is not important, and shoud be ignored.
The second line also.  In addition, the third and fifth lines are blank.

       col1          col2    col3  col4     col5

  ab   cd e      132399.4     101     0 17:25:24  Ignore anything past the last named column
       blah        773411      25    10 17:25:25  Ignore this too
```

Here, the first column, `col1`, contains the text from the beginning of the line until the character position of the end of the text string `col1`.    The second column, `col2` contains the text from the next character following the `1` in `col1` until the end of the text string `col2`.  And so on.

In reality, there are 17 columns rather than 5, but that should not change the code.

I'm looking for a data frame with the contents:

```
         col1     col2 col3 col4      col5
1   ab   cd e 132399.4  101    0  17:25:24
2        blah 773411.0   25   10  17:25:25
```

Here is a rather inelegant approach:

```
read.tt <- function(file) {
  con <- base::file(file, 'r')
  readLines(con, n=3);
  header <- readLines(con, n=1)
  close(con)
  endpoints <- c(0L, gregexpr('[^ ]( |$)', header)[[1]])
  widths <- diff(endpoints)
  names <- sapply(seq_along(widths),
                  function(i) substr(header, endpoints[i]+1, endpoints[i]+widths[i]))
  names <- sub('^ *', '', names)
  body <- read.fwf(file, widths, skip=5)
  names(body) <- names
  body
}
```

There must be a better way.

The lines to be ignored is a minor piece of this puzzle.  I'll accept a solution that works with these already removed from the file (but of course would prefer one that does not need preprocessing).

Comment: looks like job for `sed` or `awk` outside `R`

Comment: @geektrader For removing the bogus lines, yes, but how about the more important part of inferring the column widths?

Comment: I think you basically have the right approach. Read a line at a time to get to the header line, parse that is such a was as to get the column numbers that are the boundaries of the fields, and then call `read.fwf` using those boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

If you know your header line, you can get widths using following method.

```
x
## [1] "         col1     col2 col3 col4      col5"

nchar(unlist(regmatches(x, gregexpr("\\s+\\S+", x))))
## [1] 13  9  5  5 10
```

Comment: That may be more elegant than `diff(c(0L, gregexpr('[^ ]( |$)', header)[[1]]))`, but I can't assume that I know the header line.  I should read it from the file.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg You need to have some sort of pattern in the text which you want to ignore. Either, first `n` lines, or lines starting with `This` in your example.

Comment: con  <- file(filename, open = "r");
first_line <- readLines(con, n=1, warn=F);
close(con)